Volatility - own estimate vs Bloomberg's estimate
I am not an expert in volatility estimation, and results with my data give me some confusion. I would be grateful if you would help me understanding the definitions and the issue.

I have two different bonds, and in Bloomberg it is possible to download close prices (using px_last as the parameter). It is also possible to download volatility estimates. I got the following code from Bloomberg helpdesk that would give me volatility estimates for each day:

=@BDP(isin_code;"INTERVAL_VOLATILITY";"TECH_STUDIES_PARAM1_OVERRIDE=3";"END_DATE_OVERRIDE=" & Date;"MARKET_DATA_OVERRIDE=PX_LAST";"ANN_FACTOR_OVERRIDE=260.00")
the bold parameters are references to the bond isin and to the date (reference to relevant cells in Excel). This would give me volatility based on close prices of the last 3 days. Bloomberg's own definition of their volatility estimate is "Measure of risk of price moves for a
security calculated from the standard deviation of day to day logarithmic historical price changes".
But let's take an example. Suppose I have 3 days where

day t-3: Close price is 100.904
day t-2: Close price is 100.791
day t-1: Close price is 100.901
day t: Close price is 101.071

For day t Bloomberg's definition of volatility gives me 0.675702026183738 (this number is downloaded to Excel when I use the formula from above).
However, I want to know they got this number or at least get something similar. If I were to calculate the volatility myself from their definition, I would calculate logarithmic one day returns. This would give me:

log return between day t-2 and t-3: ln(100.791 / 100.904)=-0.001120504
log return between day t-1 and t-2: ln(100.901/100.791)=0.001090772
log return between day t and t-1: ln(101.071/100.901)=0.001683402

Then I calculate standard deviation of these three numbers and get 0.001477771. This is a very different number from what Bloomberg gives me when using their formula. So, what is wrong with my calculations?

The second problem is that I get opposite conclusions when comparing volatility of two bonds when I use Bloomberg volatility data and my approach presented above. So, I take two bonds and look at a period of several years (where I have an observation for each trading day). Bloomberg gives me volatility estimates for each day, and I understand that there is some overlap (because each volatility estimate is based on three numbers, so such price today will affect the volatility today, tomorrow and the day after tomorrow).

If I use a simple two-sided t-test with unequal variance then it tells me that bond1 has higher volatility. In use R and have the following code (where Volatility3d are the estimates which I get from Bloomberg - I use a screenshot because $ sign gives some issues):

So, here I see that bond 1 has a higher mean of "Volatility3d", and the p value is very close to 0. So, bond 1 has a higher volatility.
But then if I use my method, I calculate log returns for each day. Then I use a two-sided f-test to determine if the variance is equal. In R I use the following code:

And this gives me the opposite conclusion, namely that Bond2 is more volatile. Why do I get the opposite conclusions?

In general, is there a better way to test if two bonds have similar/different volatility?

Thank you!

Note that Bloomberg is using  ANN_FACTOR = 260, you are not doing annualization at all, you found a daily standard deviation. There are probably other issues also.
